# for loop after the addEventlistener() is not working but for loop inside the eventlistener is working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple javascript program. There is a problem with the javascript. When I write the for loop after the addeventlistener, It does not work.

I am following this HTML course (https://youtu.be/jS4aFq5-91M) from freecodecamp. Their code works but mine is not working. This is the code for it.

```
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const btn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
let myLeads = []
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    console.log(myLeads.length)
    console.log(myLeads)
})
for(let i=0;i<myLeads.length;i++)
{
    ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
}
```

result:
[image]

When I add the for loop inside the eventlistener it works.

```
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
const btn = document.getElementById("input-btn")
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
let myLeads = []
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
    for(let i=0;i<myLeads.length;i++)
    {
        ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
    }
})
```

result:
[image]

Why is the for loop not running when it is outside the addeventlistener? What should I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet where you have the `for loop` defined outside of the event listener, it is running as part of the script sequentially when it is loaded. As such, it will run before `myLeads` actually contains anything like so:

```
let myLeads = []
for(let i=0;i<myLeads.length;i++) { // myLeads.length = 0 so nothing happens
    ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
}
```

The code inside the `eventListener` will only trigger when you click on `btn` since that is the event you defined with `"click"`.

In your second example, since the `for loop` is inside your `eventListener` it will trigger after the button is clicked rather than when the script is loaded. As such it will run **after** `myLeads.push(inputEl.value)` resulting in `myLeads` having 1 element like so:

```
myLeads.push(inputEl.value)
for (let i = 0; i < myLeads.length; i++) { // myLeads.length = 1 so loop runs
    ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + myLeads[i] + "</li>"
}
```